# Get an element of a Google Auto Ad vignette - nested <html> document [edited]

Tags: javascript, nightwatch

I am trying to dismiss a Google ad on a website, but have no idea how to access the #dismiss-button element. Tried switching to that iframe, get "element not found"

```
    .pause(3000)
    .frame(1)
    .pause(3000) //or wait for element to be visible, same result
    .click("#dismiss-button")
```

[image: Page html]

**EDIT**: Tried to get the element by the full Xpath and now I get the "Element is not clickable at point" error. I still can't seem to find what is overlapping the button. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We need more code example of how you switch your iframe.

You can also try using `moveToElement()` following `mouseButtonDown()`